# Write an SQL query to calculate windowed sum, but taking into the account cyclicality

Tags: sql, trino

I have some data, it looks like this:

```sql
WITH temp_data AS (SELECT '1' as customer_id, 0 as weekday, 1 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' as customer_id, 1 as weekday, 8 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' as customer_id, 2 as weekday, 5 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' as customer_id, 3 as weekday, 10 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' as customer_id, 4 as weekday, 6 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' as customer_id, 5 as weekday, 5 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' as customer_id, 6 as weekday, 3 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 0 as weekday, 5 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 1 as weekday, 4 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 2 as weekday, 9 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 3 as weekday, 7 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 4 as weekday, 6 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 5 as weekday, 10 as trip_count
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as customer_id, 6 as weekday, 9 as trip_count

)
```

I want to calculate the total number of trips for each customer for each weekday within a 2 day window, so, for example, for weekday 3 the value should be the sum of values for weekdays 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
The resulting values should be: `[22, 27, 30, 34, 29, 25, 23, 22, 27, 30, 34, 29, 25, 23]`

The problem for me it that I don't know how to deal with the values on the edges. For example,
for weekday 1 the value should be the sum of values for weekdays `6, 0, 1, 2, 3`.

I tried to write something like this, but it worked incorrectly:

```sql
WITH temp_data AS (
...
),
effective_weekday AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        weekday,
        trip_count AS current_trip_count,
        ((weekday + 7 - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY weekday ASC)) % 7) AS eff_weekday
    FROM temp_data
)
SELECT
    customer_id,
    weekday,
    current_trip_count,
    SUM(current_trip_count) OVER (
        PARTITION BY customer_id, eff_weekday
        ORDER BY weekday ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING
    ) AS total_value
FROM effective_weekday
ORDER BY customer_id, weekday;
```

Comment: I'm using Trino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp_data2 as (select *
                 from temp_data
                 union all
                 select customer_id, weekday - 7, trip_count
                 from temp_data
                 union all
                 select customer_id, weekday + 7, trip_count
                 from temp_data), 
pre_final as (select customer_id,
               weekday,
               trip_count,
               sum(trip_count)
               over (partition by customer_id order by weekday ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)

        from temp_data2)
select * from pre_final
where weekday between 0 and 6
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s only 7 days so you could always just make a lookup table, lol:

```
with LookupDays as (
select 0 as LookupDay, 0 as WindowDay union
select 0 as LookupDay, 1 as WindowDay union
select 0 as LookupDay, 2 as WindowDay union
select 0 as LookupDay, 5 as WindowDay union
select 0 as LookupDay, 6 as WindowDay union
select 1 as LookupDay, 0 as WindowDay union
select 1 as LookupDay, 1 as WindowDay union
select 1 as LookupDay, 2 as WindowDay union
select 1 as LookupDay, 3 as WindowDay union
select 1 as LookupDay, 6 as WindowDay union
select 2 as LookupDay, 0 as WindowDay union
select 2 as LookupDay, 1 as WindowDay union
select 2 as LookupDay, 2 as WindowDay union
select 2 as LookupDay, 3 as WindowDay union
select 2 as LookupDay, 4 as WindowDay union
select 3 as LookupDay, 1 as WindowDay union
select 3 as LookupDay, 2 as WindowDay union
select 3 as LookupDay, 3 as WindowDay union
select 3 as LookupDay, 4 as WindowDay union
select 3 as LookupDay, 5 as WindowDay union
select 4 as LookupDay, 2 as WindowDay union
select 4 as LookupDay, 3 as WindowDay union
select 4 as LookupDay, 4 as WindowDay union
select 4 as LookupDay, 5 as WindowDay union
select 4 as LookupDay, 6 as WindowDay union
select 5 as LookupDay, 0 as WindowDay union
select 5 as LookupDay, 3 as WindowDay union
select 5 as LookupDay, 4 as WindowDay union
select 5 as LookupDay, 5 as WindowDay union
select 5 as LookupDay, 6 as WindowDay union
select 6 as LookupDay, 0 as WindowDay union
select 6 as LookupDay, 1 as WindowDay union
select 6 as LookupDay, 4 as WindowDay union
select 6 as LookupDay, 5 as WindowDay union
select 6 as LookupDay, 6 as WindowDay
)
select temp_data.customer_id, temp_data.[weekday]
    , sum(Window.trip_count)
from temp_data
    left join LookupDays L on L.LookupDay = temp_data.[weekday]
    left join temp_data Window on Window.customer_id = temp_data.customer_id
                              and Window.[weekday] = L.WindowDay
group by temp_data.customer_id, temp_data.[weekday]
order by temp_data.customer_id, temp_data.[weekday]
```

I think this should be correct?

You could also mess around with modulo, but you know… If this is part of your business logic, I’d just create the lookup table for real, not just as a CTE. I think it’s a less “magical” solution, shorter, and probably more performant than having calculations and window functions in the query.